# No output trying to use Selenium with PhpUnit and Yii on wampserver on XpPro without Netbeans

Tags: php, selenium, windows-xp, phpunit

I'm working my way through Agile-Web-Application-Development-with-Yii11-and-PHP5.

I've installed PhpUnit and Selenium and started the Selenium server from a command line and left it running.

I found a simple script to run and confirm that Selenium server is running.

When I run the functional\SiteTest.php file I get no output and SiteTest.php is opened in Netbeans, my default application for php files.

Many thanks.

Gregory.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the actual issue here is. Looks like that there is a win-api `shellexecute` call that opens the php file with netbeans (and not inside the browser). This can be system configuration or the configuration of selenium.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I couldn't delete the .php file type link but pressing the "default" button dis-associated it from Netbeans.  Then I just got no response when running the "phpunit functional\SiteTest.php" command.

Comment: I'm trying a fresh install on a VmWare virtual Xp pro machine with just wamp, pear, PHPUnit and Selenium, but was stalled last night by a problem with php reporting that curl wasn't present, when it is.

Comment: If you ask for feedback, you must add more info. Curl can be present but must not be activated. Or it needs additional libs to properly work (e.g. openssl) and such stuff.

Comment: I don't know what info is needed.  Is there a log (seems like I'd have to set one up)?

Comment: Ah.  When I run the test script from the Agile.. book on my _new_ setup on VmWare, that one comes up with php error messages, one of which says that curl is missing, so I tried to install curl!  Many thanks, Gregory.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same situation on windows in the following way:

1. Behind the scene there's an error but the php.ini hided it.
2. I've changed the display_errors = Off to display_errors = On in the php.ini.
3. Running again the functional test I've discovered that the error was in the line 11 of
   the class CWebTestCase.php (require_once('PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php')) due
   to Selenium extension missing on my pc.
4. You can verify it's missing (or not) looking at PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions directory
5. I have downloaded the extension with:  pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
6. I've revert the 2. update (again to Off).
7. I've run the phpunit functional/SiteTest.php and it works!

Enrico

Comment: I did have errors=on but saw none.  My PHPUnit_Selenium was not installed properly.  Now I'm getting output but something else is wrong.  I'll have to have a dig!  Many thanks.

Comment: Many thanks Enrico.  Sorry for the delay in responding, I've had other urgent things that needed my attention.

Comment: ...contination - new user not familiar with StackOverflow...  Knowing that it does work was useful, so I checked for SeleniumTestCase.php and installed it properly and it worked.  At least that's what my memory tells me.  Gregory.

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to run the file in a terminal window with the phpunit command:

```
phpunit functional\SiteTest.php
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I have been doing.